# Delphi PChar to C++ const char*

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I am trying to use a C++ dll from a native program. I am following the virtual method scenario as explained [here](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)

Lets say my C++ function signature is of the form

```
int Setup(const char* szIp, const char* szPort);
```

And the corresponding delphi signature is

```
function Setup(ip, port: PChar):Integer: virtual; cdecl; abstract;
```

And somewhere from the delphi program i can call

```
pObj.Setup('192.168.1.100', '97777');
```

The control comes into the dll, but szIp and szPort formal parameters only receives the first character of the ip and port that I had passed from the delphi program.

I understand that it has to do with null terminating the string properly in delphi. So i had  tried the following too.

```
var
  pzIp, pzPort: PChar;
  szIp, szPort: string; 

begin
   szIp   := '192.168.1.2';
   szPort := '9777';
   //initilize memory for pchar vars
   GetMem(pzIp, Length(szIp)+1);
   GetMem(pzPort, Length(szPort)+1);
   //null terminate the strings
   pzIp[Length(szIp)+1] := #0;
   pzPort[Length(szPort)+1] := #0;
   //copy strings to pchar
   StrPCopy(pzIp, szIp);
   StrPCopy(pzPort, szPort);
end.
```

This a'int working either. When i `Writeln` `pzIp` and `pzPort` I get strange results.

Forgot to tell, all member functions from the C++ dll are compiled with `__stdcall` and exported properly

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Delphi 2010 (and Delphi 2009) the "char" type is actually a WIDEChar - that is, 16 bits wide.  So when you call your C++ function, if that is expecting CHAR to be 8 bits wide (so called "ANSI", rather than UNICODE), then it is going to misinterpret the input parameter.

e.g. if you pass the string **'ABC'#0** (I'm showing the null terminator explicitly but this is just an implicit part of a string in Delphi and does not need to be added specifically) this passes a pointer to an **8 byte** sequence, **NOT** 4 bytes!

But because the 3 characters in your string have only 8-bit code-point values (in Unicode terms, this means that what the C++ code "sees" is a string that looks like:

```
  'A'#0'B'#0'C'#0#0#0
```

Which would explain why your C++ code seems only to be getting the first character of the string - it is seeing the **#0** in the **2nd byte** of that first character and assuming that it is the null terminator for the entire string.

You either need to modify your C++ code to correctly receive pointers to **WideChar** strings, OR modify the function signature in Delphi and convert your strings to **ANSIString** in the Delphi code *before* passing those to the C++ function:

Revised function signature:

```
  function Setup(ip, port: PANSIChar):Integer: virtual; stdcall; abstract;
```

and the corresponding "Long hand" showing conversion of strings to **ANSIString** before calling the function - the compiler may take care of this for you but you might find it helpful to make it clear in your code rather than relying on "compiler magic":

```
  var
    sIPAddress: ANSIString;
    sPort: ANSIString;
  begin   
    sIPAddress := '192.168.1.100';
    sPort      := '97777';

    pObj.Setup(sIPAddress, sPort);

    // etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation: my answer was a quick thought which proved right, but I recommend this as the answer to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Deltics, that worked. A small change though, needed to be cast to make the delphi program compile

pObj.Setup(PAnsiChar(sIPAddress), PAnsiChar(sPort));

Special thanks to @IanH too

Answer (score 4):

Is char the same size in both compilers? If you are using D2009/D2010, char is now 16-bits.

Comment: yeah i am using D2010. And my C++ code is 32 bit. So the character size should match right ?

Comment: Not necessarily: BCB4 is a 32-bit C++ compiler, but a char is a byte. You could be null-terminating your string prematurely with the 0 high-byte for the first character.

Try changing your test code above to declare szIP and szPort as AnsiString instead of string.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly your function prototype should be stdcall as well.

```
function Setup(ip, port: PChar):Integer: virtual; stdcall; abstract;
```

ps. Delphi strings are already null-terminated.

Comment: hmm, it didn't worked. The same result. But I could get rid of an access violation crash when the C++ function returned. So, i guess i am making progress :)

Comment: time to drop to assembly view :)

Comment: making it stdcall had me resolved few other issues too, +1 for the tip